# Tranposing individual pieces of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows (numbers are strings):

```
Company Name  Total Amount Due  0-10 days  10-20 days  20-30 days
ABC Company   0                 0          0           0
$5,000.00     0                 0          0           0
$5,000.00     0                 0          0           0
$0.00         0                 0          0           0
$0.00         0                 0          0           0
XYZ Company   0                 0          0           0
$10,000.00    0                 0          0           0
$8,000.00     0                 0          0           0
$2,000.00     0                 0          0           0
$0.000        0                 0          0           0
...
```

I would like to know if there's a way to do miniature transposition inside of a DataFrame. For example, I would take the values $5,000.00, $5,000.00, $0.00, and $0.00 and flip them onto the other axis:

```
Company Name  Total Amount Due  0-10 days  10-20 days  20-30 days
ABC Company  $5,000.00          $5,000.00  $0.00       $0.00
XYZ Company  $10,000.00         $8,000.00  $2,000.00   $0.00
...
```

I tried using shift and transpose, but I wasn't quite able to get the output I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the first column as numpy array

```py
out = pd.DataFrame(df['Company Name'].to_numpy().reshape((-1, 5)), columns=df.columns)
```

```
print(out)

  Company Name Total Amount Due  0-10 days 10-20 days 20-30 days
0  ABC Company        $5,000.00  $5,000.00      $0.00      $0.00
1  XYZ Company       $10,000.00  $8,000.00  $2,000.00     $0.000
```

Comment: I was able to slightly tweak this answer to get the correct answer - I used pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,6),columns=[...])